# Unable to set Device Orientation in XCUITest on Swift 4

Tags: orientation, swift4, xcode9, xcuitest

I have been running the tests successfully till Xcode 8. After updating to Xcode to 9 & 9.0.1 and upgrading to swift 4 number of problems has been araising one after the other.

Now code compiles and launches the app(Finally) but when setting the simulator orientation app crashes with following error.

> caught nsinternalinconsistencyexception activity cannot be used after its scope has completed

This is how I set my orientation

```
 XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untill xcode 8, subclassing XCUITest class and rotating the device from setup() function was allowed. But from xcode 9 it should be done only in the testFunctions()